# No way to set maximum retrieved rows in pgadmin query tool

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm using version 1.16.1, and I can't find a "max(imum) rows" param to tweak.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it in File menu -> Options... -> Query tool tab?  In 1.14.3 it is there.

Comment: @dezso: no, not it 1.16.1.  I looked and looked...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a global parameter to tweak in pgAdmin 1.16.*

As an alternative you can open tables with:

```
Tools -> View Data -> View Top 100 rows
```

This is also available from the context menu of a table in the object browser.
Once the data grid is open, a "Limit Bar" is available, where you can set a maximum for returned rows.

I would consider it a reasonable feature request to make this "Limit" element available in the "View data options" you get when you open a table with a filter (grid icon with funnel). This could also remember the last setting.

A global setting is a bit of a foot gun. People forget and then wonder why they don't get more rows.

Comment: "A global setting is a bit of a foot gun. People forget and then wonder why they don't get more rows." Good point.

Comment: "A global setting is a bit of a foot gun. People forget and then wonder why they don't get more rows." - I don't agree. When you forget to use the LIMIT clause in case of a large result set, PgAdmin may freeze...

Answer (score 0):

On table options there is Script/Select Script
Which generates default query for table.
It would be nice if that default query would contain LIMIT 1000.